# cPanel and SSH using Tunnlier or PuTTy; How?

Tags: ssh

I have a cPanel reseller account. I am trying to connect using SSH. Using Tunnlier or PuTTy i get "Shell Access is not enabled on your account.".

I have enabled it for my account; generated Public/Private keys, Authorized the public key.

I don't know what else should I do?

Comment: Are you sure your host allows this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my problem solved.

actually the SSH option in my cPanel was fake. i asked the host administrator and he opened the SSH privilege, manually and then i could easily connect to it.